# Структура таблиц для опроса с условиями

Tags: mysql, sql, инспекция-кода, проектирование

Нужно сделать опрос с условиями, где следующий вопрос будет показыватся в зависимости от ответа. 
К примеру такой вопрос: Скажите пожалуйста, у вас есть несколько минут, чтобы уточнить детали  ? *1)Да 2) Перезвоните позже.* Если вариант ответа *'Да'* то будет показыватся следующий вопрос, если нет то другой. И тд...

Набросал базову структуру таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `text` TEXT NULL, //Вопрос
    `priority` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, //приоритет вопроса
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `answers` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `question_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `text` TEXT NULL, //Вариант ответа
    `priority` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL, //приоритет ответа 
    `next_question_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL, //переходим к вопросу
);
```

Прошу оценить данную структуру БД, и подсказать что не так.

Comment: Выглядит все правильно. во второй таблице стоит добавить foreign key с ссылками на первую таблицу

Comment: @Mike *во второй таблице стоит добавить foreign key с ссылками на первую таблицу* Наверное, не надо. Может же быть ситуация, когда в таблице будут ответы, не связанные с вопросами. Тут скорее надо подумать о создании серьёзного набора процедур обслуживания и контроля данных - выборка "висячих" ответов, вопросов без ответов, зацикленных вопросов и т.п. Или вообще подумать о 2 идентичных комплектах таблиц - набираемых опросов и готовых опросов, прошедших все контроли.

Comment: @Akina Если ответ не связан с вопросом, то соответствующее поле будет NULL, foreign этого не запрещает. Он лишь контролирует, что не создадут ответ на _не существующий_ вопрос или не удалят вопрос, на который есть сслыки

Comment: @Mike В том и дело - есть реальная (реально эксплуатирующаяся) система, где как раз такое возможно, причём наличие ответов на несуществующий вопрос там допустимо именно технологически. Впрочем, справедливости ради следует сказать, что система переделывается, и планируемая структура предусматривает между вопросами и ответами классическую M:N - но опять же при сохранении возможности "висячих" ответов ("висячие вопросы" там невозможны по причине дефолтного ответа "Пропустить").

Comment: @Akina, а вы коллега автора вопроса и говорите как раз про систему, упомянутую в вопросе? Да, странные внешние условия встречаются в жизни иногда. Но от FK надо отказываться только тогда, когда для этого есть осмысленные причины. В вопросе таких причин не описано, значит FK нужен.

Comment: я что-то не понял, откуда вообще взяли эту "ответ без вопроса"?

Comment: @Мелкий В вопросе вообще ничего почти не описано. а потому имхо лучше рассмотреть и версию, которая не соответствует реальности - хрен с ею, пусть будет отброшена,- чем наоборот...

Comment: По сути FK не нужен для решения данной проблемы в моем случаи. Ответы не будут хранится в БД. Это по сути своего рода "холодный звонок" для уточнения уже сформированого заказа.